# Is it possible to save the current viewport and then re draw the saved viewport in OpenGL and C++ during the next draw cycle?

Tags: c++, opengl, bitmap

I want to know if I can save a bitmap of the current viewport in memory and then on the next draw cycle simply draw that memory to the viewport?

I'm plotting a lot of data points as a 2D scatter plot in a 256x256 area of the screen and I could in theory re render the entire plot each frame but in my case it would require me to store a lot of data points (50K-100K) most of which would be redundant as a 256x256 box only has ~65K pixels.

So instead of redrawing and rendering the entire scene at time `t` I want to take a snapshot of the scene at `t-1` and draw that first, then I can draw updates on top of that.

Is this possible? If so how can I do it, I've looked around quite a bit for clues as to how to do this but I haven't been able to find anything that makes sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you can do is render the scene into a texture and then first draw this texture (using a textured full-screen quad) before drawing the additional points. Using [FBOs](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_fbo.html) you can directly render into a texture without any data copies. If these are not supported, you can copy the current framebuffer (after drawing, of course) into a texture using [`glCopyTex(Sub)Image2D`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glCopyTexImage2D.xml).

If you don't clear the framebuffer when rendering into the texture, it already contains the data of the previous frame and you just need to render the additional points. Then all you need to do to display it is drawing the texture. So you would do something like:

1. render additional points for time t into texture (that already contains the data of time t-1) using an FBO
2. display texture by rendering textured full-screen quad into display framebuffer
3. t = t+1 -> step 1.

You might even use the [framebuffer_blit extension](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/EXT/framebuffer_blit.txt) (which is core since OpenGL 3.0, I think) to copy the FBO data onto the screen framebuffer, which might even be faster than drawing the textured quad.

Without FBOs it would be something like this (requiring a data copy):

1. render texture containing data of time t-1 into display framebuffer
2. render additional points for time t on top of the texture
3. capture framebuffer into texture (using `glCopyTexSubImage2D`) for next loop
4. t = t+1 -> step 1

Comment: At the end of the render cycle can I then grab the new frame, with the added points, and save it to the FBO for the next frame?

Comment: @slayton You don't need to, as you already rendered the scene into the FBO. See my first loop: You render each timestep into the FBO incrementally (without glClear, of course). Then the only thing you need to do is display this FBOs texture every frame (or everytime you need to draw the plot). This way you don't do any copies (except if you consider drawing the texture to the screen a copy).

Answer (score 2):

You can [render to texture](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_fbo.html#example) the heavy part. Then when rendering the scene, render that texture, and on top the changing things.